# HTML Object tag

Tags: html, object, pdf, plugins

`<object data="test.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="300" height="200">
alt : <a href="test.pdf">test.pdf</a>
</object>`

The above code displays the PDF content in html. Whether `<object>` tag requires any plugin(adobe or any other third party) to display pdf file or it is HTML capabilities.

Please clarify the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the browser. Some have native support for the PDF file format, others do not.

Answer (score 0):

Tag `<object>` requires plugins.

This tag only provides the browser with the information which browser need to know to display the content of the tag, because initially the browser don't know how to display it to the user.

Also, the text between the `<object>` and `</object>` is an alternate text, for browsers that do not support this tag.

Moreover, notice that a lot of attributes of this tag isn't supported by HTML5. More details [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_object.asp).